# popup when url redirection to itunes

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I have a URL, chizzle.com/app/download when I visit from iphone, my script detects the phone os and redirects it to specific app market. For android, it takes to play store, for apple, it takes to itunes, for other devices it takes to an Unsupported devices page.

What i dont understand here is that when we visit this URL in an iphone from skype, or make a QR code out of it and scan it, it takes to the itunes without any popup, but when the same is done from a link(FB or Google Ad campaign or a bitly link), it displays a popup whether you wan to open the page in itunes. Why would that happen????

Heres the bitly link:

bit.ly/chizzle

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the link you supplied is location-specific, so I can't see the actual iTunes URL it's redirecting to

... however ...

You should try using `itms://` or `itms-apps://` in lieu of `http(s)://` when linking to an app in the app store. The iPhone treats those slightly differently and this may resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes i tried that. Each of them. but i still got a popup. the URL for itunes is 
itms://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/chizzle-teach.-learn.-shine/id1100549622?mt=8